# import org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3PoolingDataSource

Tags: java, postgresql, netbeans

Using the code at the bottom of [this](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/pgjdbc.html#jdbc-ds-jndi) postgres documentation page, how do I import [org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3PoolingDataSource](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3PoolingDataSource.html) ?  Which driver has this class?

Comment: How to solve this , I use netbeans.I downloaded postgresql-8.4-702.jdbc4 and inlude in my libraries in my project but have problem.

Comment: How to solve **what**. And what exactly is your problem? Post the error message or sample code that shows it.

Comment: Please work on your communication skills. Coding skills alone do not count.

Comment: if you want to use org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3PoolingDataSource
: [link](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3PoolingDataSource.html) then you need to download http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc3.jar [link](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html#current)                                      make sure to look in the driver to make sure it has the class you want.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, provide more info, like stack traces :)

Anyhow, here's a primitive way see whether a particular JAR has the class you're looking for:

```
thufir@tleilax:~/postgres$ 
thufir@tleilax:~/postgres$ ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 thufir thufir 4096 2011-03-02 16:10 ./
drwxr-xr-x 75 thufir thufir 4096 2011-03-02 16:10 ../
thufir@tleilax:~/postgres$ 
thufir@tleilax:~/postgres$ wget http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc3.jar
--2011-03-02 16:11:39--  http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc3.jar
Resolving jdbc.postgresql.org... 200.46.204.71
Connecting to jdbc.postgresql.org|200.46.204.71|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 502694 (491K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc3.jar'

100%[===========================================================================>] 502,694      115K/s   in 4.4s    

2011-03-02 16:11:44 (110 KB/s) - `postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc3.jar' saved [502694/502694]

thufir@tleilax:~/postgres$ 
thufir@tleilax:~/postgres$ jar -tf postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc3.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
org/
org/postgresql/
org/postgresql/Driver$1.class
org/postgresql/Driver$ConnectThread.class
org/postgresql/Driver.class
org/postgresql/PGConnection.class
org/postgresql/PGNotification.class
org/postgresql/PGRefCursorResultSet.class
org/postgresql/PGResultSetMetaData.class
org/postgresql/PGStatement.class
org/postgresql/copy/
org/postgresql/copy/CopyIn.class
org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.class
org/postgresql/copy/CopyOperation.class
org/postgresql/copy/CopyOut.class
org/postgresql/copy/PGCopyInputStream.class
org/postgresql/copy/PGCopyOutputStream.class
org/postgresql/core/
org/postgresql/core/BaseConnection.class
org/postgresql/core/BaseResultSet.class
org/postgresql/core/BaseStatement.class
org/postgresql/core/ConnectionFactory.class
org/postgresql/core/Encoding.class
org/postgresql/core/Field.class
org/postgresql/core/Logger.class
org/postgresql/core/Notification.class
org/postgresql/core/Oid.class
org/postgresql/core/PGBindException.class
org/postgresql/core/PGStream$1.class
org/postgresql/core/PGStream.class
org/postgresql/core/ParameterList.class
org/postgresql/core/Parser.class
org/postgresql/core/ProtocolConnection.class
org/postgresql/core/Query.class
org/postgresql/core/QueryExecutor.class
org/postgresql/core/ResultCursor.class
org/postgresql/core/ResultHandler.class
org/postgresql/core/TypeInfo.class
org/postgresql/core/UTF8Encoding.class
org/postgresql/core/Utils.class
org/postgresql/core/VisibleBufferedInputStream.class
org/postgresql/core/types/
org/postgresql/core/types/PGBigDecimal.class
org/postgresql/core/types/PGBoolean.class
org/postgresql/core/types/PGByte.class
org/postgresql/core/types/PGDouble.class
org/postgresql/core/types/PGFloat.class
org/postgresql/core/types/PGInteger.class
org/postgresql/core/types/PGLong.class
org/postgresql/core/types/PGNumber.class
org/postgresql/core/types/PGShort.class
org/postgresql/core/types/PGString.class
org/postgresql/core/types/PGType.class
org/postgresql/core/types/PGUnknown.class
org/postgresql/core/v2/
org/postgresql/core/v2/ConnectionFactoryImpl$SimpleResultHandler.class
org/postgresql/core/v2/ConnectionFactoryImpl.class
org/postgresql/core/v2/FastpathParameterList.class
org/postgresql/core/v2/ProtocolConnectionImpl.class
org/postgresql/core/v2/QueryExecutorImpl$1.class
org/postgresql/core/v2/QueryExecutorImpl$2.class
org/postgresql/core/v2/QueryExecutorImpl$3.class
org/postgresql/core/v2/QueryExecutorImpl.class
org/postgresql/core/v2/SimpleParameterList.class
org/postgresql/core/v2/V2Query.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/
org/postgresql/core/v3/CompositeParameterList.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/CompositeQuery.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/ConnectionFactoryImpl$1.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/ConnectionFactoryImpl$UnsupportedProtocolException.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/ConnectionFactoryImpl.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/CopyInImpl.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/CopyOperationImpl.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/CopyOutImpl.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/Portal.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/ProtocolConnectionImpl.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/QueryExecutorImpl$1.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/QueryExecutorImpl$2.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/QueryExecutorImpl$3.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/QueryExecutorImpl$ErrorTrackingResultHandler.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/QueryExecutorImpl.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/SimpleParameterList.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/SimpleQuery.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/V3ParameterList.class
org/postgresql/core/v3/V3Query.class
org/postgresql/ds/
org/postgresql/ds/PGConnectionPoolDataSource.class
org/postgresql/ds/PGPooledConnection.class
org/postgresql/ds/PGPoolingDataSource.class
org/postgresql/ds/PGSimpleDataSource.class
org/postgresql/ds/common/
org/postgresql/ds/common/BaseDataSource.class
org/postgresql/ds/common/PGObjectFactory.class
org/postgresql/ds/jdbc23/
org/postgresql/ds/jdbc23/AbstractJdbc23PooledConnection$ConnectionHandler.class
org/postgresql/ds/jdbc23/AbstractJdbc23PooledConnection$StatementHandler.class
org/postgresql/ds/jdbc23/AbstractJdbc23PooledConnection.class
org/postgresql/ds/jdbc23/AbstractJdbc23PoolingDataSource$1.class
org/postgresql/ds/jdbc23/AbstractJdbc23PoolingDataSource.class
org/postgresql/ds/jdbc23/AbstractJdbc23SimpleDataSource.class
org/postgresql/fastpath/
org/postgresql/fastpath/Fastpath.class
org/postgresql/fastpath/FastpathArg.class
org/postgresql/geometric/
org/postgresql/geometric/PGbox.class
org/postgresql/geometric/PGcircle.class
org/postgresql/geometric/PGline.class
org/postgresql/geometric/PGlseg.class
org/postgresql/geometric/PGpath.class
org/postgresql/geometric/PGpoint.class
org/postgresql/geometric/PGpolygon.class
org/postgresql/gss/
org/postgresql/gss/GSSCallbackHandler.class
org/postgresql/gss/GssAction.class
org/postgresql/gss/MakeGSS.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Array$1.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Array$PgArrayList.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Array.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Blob.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2BlobClob$LOIterator.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2BlobClob.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Clob.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Connection$1.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Connection$TransactionCommandHandler.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Connection.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2ResultSet$CursorResultHandler.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2ResultSet$NullObject.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2ResultSet$PrimaryKey.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2ResultSetMetaData.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Statement$CallableBatchResultHandler.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Statement$StatementResultHandler.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Statement.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/EscapedFunctions.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/ResultWrapper.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/TimestampUtils$1.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/TimestampUtils$ParsedTimestamp.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/TimestampUtils.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/TypeInfoCache.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/optional/
org/postgresql/jdbc2/optional/ConnectionPool.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/optional/PoolingDataSource.class
org/postgresql/jdbc2/optional/SimpleDataSource.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/
org/postgresql/jdbc3/AbstractJdbc3Blob.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/AbstractJdbc3Clob.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/AbstractJdbc3Connection.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/AbstractJdbc3DatabaseMetaData.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/AbstractJdbc3ParameterMetaData.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/AbstractJdbc3ResultSet.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/AbstractJdbc3Statement.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3Array.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3Blob.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3CallableStatement.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3Clob.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3Connection.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3ConnectionPool.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3DatabaseMetaData.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3ParameterMetaData.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3PoolingDataSource.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3PreparedStatement.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3ResultSet.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3ResultSetMetaData.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3SimpleDataSource.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/Jdbc3Statement.class
org/postgresql/jdbc3/PSQLSavepoint.class
org/postgresql/largeobject/
org/postgresql/largeobject/BlobInputStream.class
org/postgresql/largeobject/BlobOutputStream.class
org/postgresql/largeobject/LargeObject.class
org/postgresql/largeobject/LargeObjectManager.class
org/postgresql/ssl/
org/postgresql/ssl/MakeSSL.class
org/postgresql/ssl/NonValidatingFactory$NonValidatingTM.class
org/postgresql/ssl/NonValidatingFactory.class
org/postgresql/ssl/WrappedFactory.class
org/postgresql/util/
org/postgresql/util/Base64.class
org/postgresql/util/GT.class
org/postgresql/util/MD5Digest.class
org/postgresql/util/PGInterval.class
org/postgresql/util/PGbytea.class
org/postgresql/util/PGmoney.class
org/postgresql/util/PGobject.class
org/postgresql/util/PGtokenizer.class
org/postgresql/util/PSQLDriverVersion.class
org/postgresql/util/PSQLException.class
org/postgresql/util/PSQLState.class
org/postgresql/util/PSQLWarning.class
org/postgresql/util/ServerErrorMessage.class
org/postgresql/util/StreamWrapper.class
org/postgresql/util/UnixCrypt.class
org/postgresql/xa/
org/postgresql/xa/PGXAConnection$ConnectionHandler.class
org/postgresql/xa/PGXAConnection.class
org/postgresql/xa/PGXADataSource.class
org/postgresql/xa/PGXADataSourceFactory.class
org/postgresql/xa/PGXAException.class
org/postgresql/xa/RecoveredXid.class
org/postgresql/translation/
org/postgresql/translation/messages_bg.class
org/postgresql/translation/messages_cs.class
org/postgresql/translation/messages_de.class
org/postgresql/translation/messages_es.class
org/postgresql/translation/messages_fr.class
org/postgresql/translation/messages_it.class
org/postgresql/translation/messages_ja.class
org/postgresql/translation/messages_nl.class
org/postgresql/translation/messages_pl.class
org/postgresql/translation/messages_pt_BR.class
org/postgresql/translation/messages_ru.class
org/postgresql/translation/messages_sr.class
org/postgresql/translation/messages_tr.class
org/postgresql/translation/messages_zh_CN.class
org/postgresql/translation/messages_zh_TW.class
META-INF/services/
META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver
thufir@tleilax:~/postgres$ 
thufir@tleilax:~/postgres$
```

and, there's your class:   org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3PoolingDataSource

So, providing that this JAR is on your classpath, you should now be able to import this class into your code.

when you ask questions on stackoverflow, please include actual code samples and stack traces.

Hope that helps :)

Incidentally, the problem was just that you were using the JDBC4 driver when the JDBC3 driver was required.  No big deal.